# Parent view not setting global variable on <webview> in Electron after updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, webview, electron

I am trying to require a module in a guest page (angular controller).

When the application used an older version of node (0.30.5) it worked perfectly well. However i've had to upgrade electron to the latest version (0.37.6), and ive updated all uses of `ipc` in the electron application, so that it's now `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer`.

Previously the angular controller managed to require the module using:

```
var ipc = window['require']('ipc');
```

So i thought that changing it to:

```
var ipcRenderer = window['require']('electron').ipcRenderer;
```

However that does not work and it states that ***window.require is not a function***. I've tried multiple times to get it to work with other methods, however nothing works so far.

The problem is that require is **undefined**, however require is set in the html file that contains the `<webview>`, so it should be defined.

The `<webview>` goes to a URL which returns a `<div>` that uses angular.

The angular controller that is used in that `<div>` is no longer working, as the module I need is the first thing to be set in the file, and it is undefined

**EDIT:**

I can now see that the property that I set in the html is visible in the application debugger, however it does not appear in the webview debugger.

So I can only assume the parent view does not pass on the value to the `<webview>`. So if anyone knows why it doesn't pass on the value or what I need to do to set it, I would appreciate any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as of the current version of Electron (0.37.6) the way to set a global variable is to specify a preload script on the `preload` attribute on the `<webview>` tag. For example in the preload script:

```
window['ipcRenderer'] = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
```

This will allow the guest page that the `<webview>` is displaying, to use the ipcRenderer. It seems like the previous method i was using, which was setting the global variable in the parent view HTML, does not work anymore

Answer (score 0):

It's a quite old way to require electron modules. Here's the new one:

```
var ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
```

Comment: Thats what i tried... and it didn't work. Any other suggestions? I tried to go by the electron FAQs and that seemed to break other things in the application. Thanks